# passing variable to django custom template tag

Tags: django-profiles

Im using django-profiles. In my profile_detail template I know that I will receive a **profile** variable.

I want to make a custom tag that gets the content per user via user id. Like this:

```
{% get_user_content book.review profile.user.id as review_list %}
```

However, when  my parser runs It seems like profile.user.id was not transformed to an id number and throws an exception.

I can verify that my custom tag works by changing profile.user.id to say 1 for admin.

```
{% get_user_content book.review 1 as review_list %}
```

Has anyone deals with it before? What did you do?

Answer (score 1):

Template tags never translate arguments. You need to do the lookup in the context yourself.

Comment: Can you pls guide me on how to do context lookup?

Comment: You clearly know how to set it. All you have to do is get it instead. Hint: `getattr()`.